# sed: unterminated address regex

Tags: linux, bash, sed

From what I read about sed, multiple instructions within braces should work.

The second sed command works fine.
But why would the first sed command below fail?

```
echo "-------"

sed -e '/UNCOMMENT THIS/,/jmx/ { \
    /foo/d \
    /test/d \
}' \
test.txt

echo "-------"

sed -e '/UNCOMMENT THIS/,/jmx/ { /foo/d; /test/d }' \
test.txt

echo "-------"
```

Test.txt

```
  <!--  To enable authentication security checks, uncomment the following security domain name -->
  <!--UNCOMMENT THIS
  foo
  test
  <property name="securityDomain">jmx-console</property>
  -->
```

Comment: Can you provide a `test.txt` sample?

Comment: Why did you add backslash in front of each newline inside the sed script?

Comment: lol. so that explains the error. I thought bash shell required backslashes even for the sed instructions on multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between single quotes (`'`) the backslashes are interpreted as "real backslashes", so the escape characters are not interpreted".

You can resolve this by simply using a new line without the backslash in the quote environment:

```
sed -e '/UNCOMMENT THIS/,/jmx/ {
    /foo/d
    /test/d
}' \
 test.txt
```

As you see, you need to provide a backslash at the end of the command, to ensure `test.txt` is grouped with the command call. But `bash` automatically groups content between two single quotes.